# No company mode found in packages list

Tags: company-mode, completion

I want to install the company mode, but searching in the `M-x list-packages` i find no company mode found, but a bunch of company backends for different languages. How should i install company? 
PS: This is my init.el file beginning:

```
(require 'package) 

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; elpy
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/") t)
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

(package-initialize)
```

Comment: `company-mode` should be part of GNU Emacs, i.e. there is no need to install it separately. What version of Emacs are you using (`M-x emacs-version`)?

Comment: I have Emacs 24.4.1. So it suffices to add `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)` to the `init.el` file?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Also [consider using the sharp quote (`#'`)](http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html) for functions like `global-company-mode`.

Comment: "company-mode should be part of GNU Emacs" No, it isn't.

Comment: @Dmitry The `company.el` file says `;; This file is part of GNU Emacs.`

Comment: @TianxiangXiong Do you see which directory this file is in?

Comment: @TianxiangXiong Company is available from ELPA, which is the official package repository and is enabled by default. The license text is required as part of submitting to ELPA. It is still necessary to actually install the package to use it.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was under the impression that the blurb was required only for code shipped with Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

The bit of configuration you provided does not actually evaluate, so I suspect your package list is not configured correctly. (Try it: copy your `add-to-list` code above in to a scratch buffer and then call `M-x eval-buffer` to see the error.)

Use `C-h v package-archives` to check the value. Or try the Customize interface, with: `M-x customize-option package-archives`.

Note that `company` is *not* part of the standard Emacs distribution and must be installed. However, it *is* available in the GNU ELPA repository, which should already be configured in the default `package-archives`. So you should be able to start Emacs without any custom configuration and use `package-install` to install it.

See: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/company.html

Comment: I tried to install company with `package-install`, there are only company-backends as choice. I cannot see any `company` to install

Comment: Did you try removing your package archives configuration or checking what the actual value is? As I noted one can start a clean installation of Emacs with no customization and install as described, so there must be a non-default configuration here that is causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

`'package-archives` is a list of dotted pairs. So your code should be:

```
(setq package-archives
      '(("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
        ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))
```